# Is there a Class.forName() equivalent for Apex

Tags: sobject, class, describesobject

I'm looking to dynamically instantiate a class by its name. How can I do that in Apex? I thought about a factory method with a series of if-else statements, but am not satisfied with that as it isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems something like that is possible with:

```
System.Type objType = Type.forName(objName);
Object obj = objType.newInstance();
```

Comment: Please note that it has to have an empty constructor in order to do so.